# extjs grid header context menu - "choose column menu" behind taskbar

Tags: html, css, extjs, grid, z-index

I am using extjs 4 Desktop

I got a grid with a lot of columns.
I want to hide/unhide via context menu.

The taskbar got a high z-index to stay in front,
i gave the vertical scroller a higher z-index,
but it remains behind the taskbar.

```
.x-panel .x-layer .x-panel-default .x-menu .x-vertical-scroller .x-panel-vertical-scroller
  .x-panel-default-vertical-scroller { z-index:9999999; }
```

The CSS i took from browser-console, when I change z-index there, it works.

Something is missing!

Comment: Try adding !important after your CSS rule- does that work? If so it will be a specificity/ordering issue with your CSS (z-index:9999999!important;)

Comment: indeed it works, but how to achieve without?